# using ETag with Facebook but the status code is always 200 and not 304

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, synchronization, etag, if-none-match

When I try to call a request for the the https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,link,picture&access_token=MyAccessToken with the ETag I always get the request code as 200 every time. I made two back to back response and checked it. The change was at the end it had a section for pagination and it attached a access token. which is always different so the ETag value also changes. 
I tried to use REStClient Add-on in Firefox but the same behavior. I also tried Firebug and Modify Headers Add-ons as mentioned [Here in Facebook Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/627/) but no change. 
I tried to call another request /me? and it works as expected, but for /me/friends and /me/events, it always returns 200 response. Any help is appreciated.

This question is similar to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800893/using-etag-but-the-status-code-is-always-200-and-not-304/16994586#16994586) but the answer does not work with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a bug in Facebook Graph API. I think the problem is that "next" value in Paging section is different in each request so it always returns 200. Here is a link which describes the problem of Paging even there is no more data in such pages [Facebook Graph API JSON result has Page Next, despite no more data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502080/facebook-graph-api-json-result-has-page-next-despite-no-more-data) and [the developer blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/30/updates-to-the-graph-api/) about paging issue.

In both links there is no direct solution about my question,but this is my conclusion that not modified does not work with friends api because unwanted paging section which has no data and has "_after_id" value always changes in each request.